# Ints in C printint weird thing

Tags: c, int, printf

I don't understand why this code would print 24 and 20.

```
int main(){ 
    int m = 24, n = 024;
    printf("%d %d", m, n); 
    return 0; 
}
```

Comment: `024` is an octal constant, `2*8 + 4 = 20`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In C, numerals starting with “0” are octal. So `024` means 24<sub>8</sub>, which is 2•8 + 4 = 20.

Answer (score 3):

Leading 0 indicates octal, that's base 8. So:

```
 2 * 8 + 4 == 20
```